# SQL Select top 3 rows with highest value in a certain column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi Stackoverflow users,

I'm currently working on a small website and I need a SQL query that selects 3 rows with the most 'Likes'. I've tried using max and top 3 but nothing seem to work for me. I would appreciate some help from you guys! Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Why can't you do Top 3 with OrderBy Likes Descending

Answer (score 6):

Using `TOP` won't work with MySQL, because that is SQL Server (or maybe Access) syntax.  You probably want `LIMIT` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Likes DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

We could have also used:

```
LIMIT 3, OFFSET 0;  -- three records with no offset
LIMIT 0, 3          -- same as above
```

Comment: Works like a charm! (Didn't know LIMIT was even a thing)

Comment: LIMIT has two parameter first is starting point and second is closing point, in your case use LIMIT 0, 3.  by default first parameter is 0